# Change LayoutMdi from parent form when closing child form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm currently working with forms and mdi. In my project there is a mainform (a mdiContainer) which can have x subforms. I want to reach, that everytime, a subform is closed, all other subforms where arranged again.

You can do that with writing this into the mainform:

```
public void resetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical);
}
```

In the subform, i do this:

```
private void subform_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Form1 mainform = new Form1();
    mainform.resetToolStripMenuItem_Click(mainform, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
  catch
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("error");
  }
}
```

It does not give any error, but also wont arrange the subforms again. I also tried to call the method with other parameters.

Any idea how i can make this work?

Comment: You're starting a new mainform every time you close a child form.  Try deleting that line.  The mdi parent shouldn't need to be re-initialized whenever a child is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should make you pause:

```
Form1 mainform = new Form1();
```

You made a new form, so you aren't referencing the existing one.

But I think there are issues trying to do this from the child form.

It's probably better to listen to the Closed event of the child from the MDIParent, like this:

```
ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.FormClosed += childForm_FormClosed;
childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Show();
```

And then in the Closed method, call the code:

```
void childForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
    resetToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null);
  }));
}
```

I used BeginInvoke because otherwise, the closed child form is still being included in the layout tiling.

Comment: Cant do that, childForm.FormClosed += childForm_FormClosed and this.BeginInvoke.. gives me the error: doesnt exists in this context...

Comment: @user3616874 Can't see what you did, but all of this code is in the MDI parent.

Comment: oh ok. i correct that in my project. But still, it will just do nothing. It just runs without error.

Comment: @user3616874 Well, I can only help you with the code that you posted.  All of your child forms need to call that childForm_FormClosed event.  Do get rid of the current `subform_FormClosed` event, too.